# how to integrate an existing web application with an android App

Tags: android

I am just learning application development using Android platform. I want to know how if we post something in twitter app will go to twitter..how do they integrate these two ?

Thanks,
Ananth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android webkit webview..

There is a small example in samples in the SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using [this](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)